# Module '...node_modules/ionic-angular/index"' has no exported member 'Page'

Tags: angular, ionic3

i followed the instcructions of this tutorial:
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/add-barcode-scanning-functionality-to-your-ionic-2-app/
However, starting the app, I get the error message:

> Typescript Error
>   'Module "Path/node_modules/ionic-angular/index"'
>   has no exported member 'Page'.

My Code is:

```
import {Page, Platform, Alert, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
static get parameters() {
    return [[Platform], [NavController]];
}

constructor(platform, navController) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.navController = navController;
}

scan() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan((result) => {
            this.nav.present(Alert.create({
                title: "Scan Results",
                subTitle: result.text,
                buttons: ["Close"]
            }));
        }, (error) => {
            this.nav.present(Alert.create({
                title: "Attention!",
                subTitle: error,
                buttons: ["Close"]
            }));
        });
    });
}
}
```

I have absolutely no Idea what to do. I am also new in Ionic, therefore I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Component` instead of `@Page`. 
@Page is now deprecated

Checkout https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/difference-between-page-and-component/55287